# Syntax Method For A Type-class

Tags: scala

I have the following simple typeclass implementation:

```scala
sealed trait Foo

object Foo {
  case object A extends Foo
  case object B extends Foo
}

sealed trait Baz

object Baz {
  case object C extends Baz
  case object D extends Baz
}

trait TC[C <: Foo, T <: Baz] {
  val data: String
}

object instances {

  implicit val a: TC[Foo.A.type, Baz.C.type] = new TC[Foo.A.type, Baz.C.type] {
    val data = "some data"
  }

  implicit val b: TC[Foo.A.type, Baz.D.type] = new TC[Foo.A.type, Baz.D.type] {
    val data = "some other data"
  }

}

object syntax {
  
  def getData[A <: Foo](b: Baz): String =
    b match {
      case Baz.C => implicitly[TC[A, Baz.C.type]].data
      case Baz.D => implicitly[TC[A, Baz.D.type]].data
    }

}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```scala
could not find implicit value for parameter e: TC[A,Baz.C.type]
case Baz.C => implicitly[TC[A, Baz.C.type]].data
```

Is it not possible to write such a polymorphic function and have the type class instance be resolved?

Comment: `getData[Foo.B.type](Baz.C) = ???`, `getData[Foo](Baz.C) = ???`, `getData[Foo.A.type with Foo.B.type](Baz.C) = ???`, `getData[Nothing](Baz.C) = ???`, `getData[Null](Baz.C) = ???`, `getData[Foo with Seq[Int]](Baz.C) = ???`. So, *so* many things that can go wrong.

Comment: The idea of a **typeclass** is to avoid having those pattern matches. Maybe it would help if you can describe your real issue with more detail.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I showed the simple example as I thought it would be the easiest way to understand the problem. Basically what I want is to expose some method that return the correct value based on upon the type of Foo and type of Baz that is calling it.

Comment: so basically what you are saying is that typeclass mechanism should not be used with ADT

Comment: The problem is that you want the type of `B` to be actually known at runtime, is that right? - Anyways, the main problem right now is that your instances aren't in scope and that the compiler can't know that there will be an instance for any `T <: Foo`

Comment: yes thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this

```scala
trait TC[T <: Foo] {
  def getData(b: Baz): String
}

object TC {
  def getData[T <: Foo](b: Baz)(implicit ev: TC[T]): String =
    ev.getData(b)

  implicit final val TCA: TC[A] = {
    case C => "Data 1"
    case D => "Data 2"
  }

  // More instances.
}
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for any reason.
I may have some syntax errors, but I hope the idea is clear

Comment: so are you saying that I cannot have two type parameters for the type class? because one has to be resolved at runtime?

Comment: @Mojo yes, you can have two type parameters, but since your second type will depend on a runtime value then you would need to do a pattern match. I just think this design is simpler.

Comment: I posted a possible solution but I have no idea how it works. I couldn't update my original post and SO wouldn't let me so added it as an answer instead. How is that working??

Comment: In the end I settled for this approach, simply because Baz cannot be resolved at compile time. It's value is only known at runtime

Answer (score 0):

This works but I have no idea how??

```scala
sealed trait Foo

object Foo {
  case object A extends Foo
  case object B extends Foo
}

sealed trait Baz

object Baz {
  case object C extends Baz
  case object D extends Baz
}

trait TC[C <: Foo, B <: Baz] {
  val data: String
}

object TC {

  implicit val a: TC[Foo.A.type, Baz.C.type] = new TC[Foo.A.type, Baz.C.type] {
    val data = "some data"
  }

  implicit val b: TC[Foo.A.type, Baz.D.type] = new TC[Foo.A.type, Baz.D.type] {
    val data = "some other data"
  }

}

object syntax {

  def getData[A <: Foo, B <: Baz](b: B)(implicit ev: TC[A, B]): String = implicitly[TC[A, B]].data

}

syntax.getData(Baz.D) // returns "some other date"
```

Comment: I didn't even tell it about which `Foo` it should use to locate the typeclass instance so not sure how this works???

Comment: it's because there is only instance with Baz.D so it picks that one - if there are two then it leads to ambiguous implicits - SHIT!

Comment: The compiler always tries too hard to compile, so in this case it just infers something that worked. How and which and if it is deterministic or not is outside of my knowledge. But in general, this won't work at all because you need to specify both type parameters which defeats the purpose of passing a value of type `Baz` if you can specify both types at compile time rather than at runtime then yeah this works, I would just use `ev` directly rather than summoning it again with `implicitly`

Comment: This is one of the things I hate about scala- implicit resolution rules. There is no way I am going to spend all that time learning all them rules and trying to guess what the compiler is going to do with my code.

Comment: Is actually very simple if you follow good design guidelines. Implicits are resolved at compile time and are based on types.